# Opening local html file with SlimerJS

Tags: phantomjs, slimerjs

I have a script that works in PhantomJS but I'm trying to switch to SlimerJS. I keep getting an error when trying to open a local file:

```SlimerJS
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 2048, height: 1536 };
console.log('Processing',system.args[1]);
page.open(
  'simple.html',
  function start(status) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      page.render(system.args[2], {format: 'png'});
      phantom.exit();
    },1000);
  }
);
```

`simple.html` is a file located in the same directory as the script. The resulting PNG says "Address Not Found", "simple.html could not be found. Please check the name and try again."

I've also tried:

- full OS path, eg `/User/blah/blah/simple.html`
- file URI `file:///Users/blah/blah/simple.html`

These yield a similar result.

I'd rather not have the script publicly available for a variety of reasons. Is it possible to launch a local file with SlimerJS?

Comment: This is likely a bug. I'm on windows and I couldn't even write a workaround with `page.onLoadFinished = function(){/* something*/}; page.content = fs.read('simple.html');`. Maybe you can write an issue [here](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues) and link it as a comment.

Comment: looks like it may not be possible: http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/webpage.html#open-url

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. Reading the docs it specifies a url.

I got around this by running a http server

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then accessing it through localhost.

```
page.open('http://localhost:8000/simple.html',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

A file URI does work. Something like `file:///Users/name/project/file.html`.